# Use gsub to remove pattern from a string: argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I am trying to remove pattern from string with gsub from the following array of `chr`

```
articles<-c("RT @name1: hello world", "@nickname1: bye bye guys", 
"RT @name2_surname2: I have no text", "Hello!")
```

The pattern is formed by the terms between `@` and `:` only in the strings that begin with `RT`. Hence in our case the pattern is:

```
 "name1"    "name2_surname2"
```

The pattern can be obtained by using

```
pat <- "^RT.*?@(.*?):.*"
res <- gsub(pat,"\\1",articles[grepl(pat,articles)])
```

After removal of this pattern, the desired result is so:

```
"RT : hello world", "@nickname1: bye bye guys", 
"RT : I have no text", "Hello!"
```

Anyway, when I use:

```
gsub(res,"",articles)
```

I obtain a wrong result:

```
[1] "RT @: hello world"                  "@nick: bye bye guys"               
[3] "RT @name2_surname2: I have no text" "Hello!"                            
Warning message:
In gsub(res, "", articles) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: The problem with your code is that `res` is a vector with two elements; that's why you get the error that `argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`. If you paste the two elements together, as suggested by @Akrun, you can use that as the pattern for `gsub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `paste` the patterns to a single string and use that in `gsub` pattern as the `pattern` argument is not vectorized i.e, it takes only a length of 1

```
gsub(paste0("\\b(", paste(res, collapse="|"),  ")\\b"), "", articles)
#[1] "RT @: hello world"        "@nickname1: bye bye guys" "RT @: I have no text"     "Hello!"
```

Comment: The desired result is this: `"RT : hello world", "@nickname1: bye bye guys", 
"RT : I have no text", "Hello!"`

Comment: Your solution works if you change `pat` to `pat <- "^RT.*?(@.*?):.*"`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann tthanks, that is also good.  I added a. word boundary in case the OP wanted to keep his pattern as such

Answer (score 2):

If the desired output is, as stated, this:

```
"RT : hello world", "@nickname1: bye bye guys", "RT : I have no text", "Hello!"
```

then this solution works:

First, you need to change the pattern to include `@` in the capturing group:

```
pat <- "^RT.*?(@.*?):.*"
res <- gsub(pat,"\\1",articles[grepl(pat,articles)])
```

Then, as suggested by @Akrun, you can paste the two vector elements of `res`together, which allows you to use it as a (single) pattern:

```
gsub(paste0(res, collapse = "|"), "", articles)
```

That will give you the disired output.